# I accidentally charged sales tax to a tax exempt client. Can I simply refund them?

Tags: united-states, taxes, new-york, sales-tax

I accidentally charged sales tax to a tax exempt client. I realized this as I was preparing to pay sales tax to the state.

What's the correct procedure here? Do I simply send the accidentally collected money back to the client and (for all practical purposes) pretend it never happened? Or is this something I should report as overcollected sales tax?

Both me and my client are located in New York State.

Comment: This isn't exactly a question about personal finance, is it?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure which area to put this question in. I saw that there were a bunch of other sales tax questions in "personal finance & money", though, so I thought it may be the right place. I'd be happy to ask elsewhere if you know of a better board :-)

Comment: Also, isn't this a forum(ish) for both personal finance AND *money* (in general)? :-)

Comment: It's confusing, but no. It is a personal finance site. Business and economics questions are generally off topic unless there is some link to personal finance.

Comment: Well, I'm a sole proprietor, so it's kind of personal :-D. haha. That's okay. Point taken. Is there a Stack site for this type of question? Questions about sales tax/etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If they have a document that says they paid sales tax, then you *must* have a document that says you refunded it. Otherwise, your tax office might find out that you charged sales tax, you have no proof of the refund, so it very much looks like tax evasion. I'd call your tax office to hear what they say about it.

Comment: Just spoke with the NYS sales tax information center and they said "Just refund it and then file as if you hadn't collected it."

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- you can refund the sales tax and adjust your return. Make sure you have a copy of your customer's reseller permit on file.

If the item sold was for their own use (instead of resale), then sales tax is due, so you might want to check with the customer and ask them what they want to do.

Comment: It was a website, so it's definitely for their own use; not resale. Is it okay for me to just refund them and (in my payment to the state) just act as if it was never collected?